# How to change Default Values of Android XML using Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-xml

as you guys know on graphical layout default buttons , textviews etc ID's appear as

```
android:id="@+id/Button1"
android:id="@+id/TextView1"
```

When I name my id's I prefer starting with "b" for buttons , "tv" for textviews.

so my question is it possible to name my id's b1,b2 , tv1 , tv2  etc as default ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't change default values, but you can easily change ID of view.
In GUI editor, right click on element and click option 'Edit ID...' and then just type what you want

Comment: I know about that but I just wanna make my own default id's so instead of remove all those characters everytime I'll just put the name after default value.

Answer (score 0):

Id generation is hardcoded into ADT, it based on a widget's class name (also works for user defined classes).